# On-demand removal - should i block off with robots.txt?

Tags: google-search-console

Has anyone tried the on-demand removal tool?

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/indexing

I created a sitemap with a bunch of old urls with an expiration that are being 404ed. Also I edited my robots.txt to disallow crawling of the old directory. When I submit my new sitemap of expired links though, I get a warning message that the robots.txt is blocking off that directory.

So I'm not sure if I need to remove it from robots.txt or leave it.  I keep reading conflicting things whether or not to edit the robots.txt.

Comment: The order of removing a page from the index is: 404 or 410 error (if gone); or robots.txt; or noindex. Do not be in a hurry. Search engines are notoriously slow no matter what you do. Do not try and make any search engine real-time. It is not possible. Do not make them mad trying.

Answer (score 1):

> When I submit my new sitemap of expired links
> though,

You should not use expired urls in a sitemap. They are only for current urls.
There is no valid syntax in sitemaps to indicate a removed url.

From http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html see

> Excluding content
>
> The Sitemaps protocol enables you to let search engines know what
> content you would like indexed. To tell search engines the content you
> don't want indexed, use a robots.txt file or robots meta tag. See
> robotstxt.org for more information on how to exclude content from
> search engines.
>
> I get a warning message that the robots.txt is blocking off
> that directory.

Whats happening is that googlebot sees the url in your sitemap, tries to access it but get blocked by your robots.txt.

It's a misunderstanding, you think you're asking google to delete the url and googlebot thinks you are asking it to crawl a link but then it gets blocked by your robots.txt

> So I'm not sure if I need to remove it from robots.txt or leave it. I
> keep reading conflicting things whether or not to edit the robots.txt.

The correct procedure is as follows ...

- configure your web server to return a 404 response for all deleted urls
- configure your web server to show the visitor a helpful "404 help" page (optional but nice)
- remove the deleted urls from your robots.txt (this will allow google to try to request them, get the 404 response and understand correctly that the urls have been deleted)
- submit an updated sitemap that **only contains currently existing urls that you want google to crawl and index**.

As regards

> Has anyone tried the on-demand removal tool?
>
> https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/indexing

The "on-demand removal" tool only applies to "[Google Custom Search](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/overview)". It has no effect on the general Google search public search index.

Think of "[Google Custom Search](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/overview)" as an entirely separate private search engine just for your site. It just happens to be implemented by Google.

Note that robots.txt has no effect on "[Google Custom Search](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/overview)".

Note that "[Google Custom Search](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/overview)" & the general Google search public search index use separate sitemaps that do not influence each other.

You can create and manage "custom search" instances from within the ["Google Search Console" (recently renamed from "Google Webmaster Tools")](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Webmaster_Tools)

Log into "Search Console", click "Other Resources" at the bottom of the left menu. Then click on

"*Custom Search : Harness the power of Google to create a customized search experience for your own website.*" in the list displayed.

**Assuming you are were using a "Custom Search"** and wish to remove urls from it's index *immediately*, you must prefix the URL with a "-" symbol, and submit it in the "*On-demand indexing using individual URLs*" tool within the "*Other Resources* -> *Custom Search*" section of the "*Google Search Console*" website.

If it's not that urgent you can remove urls from a "Custom Search" index by submitting an updated sitemap that applies only to that "Custom Search" index.

Comment: Ok, I'm concerned mainly with the internatl search so google custom search engine. When i login to cse.google.com, and try "Indexing" tab,  I never get any results back. It just times out. Tried with IE and firefox.